# Sklearn TFIDF vectorizer to run as parallel jobs

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How run sklearn TFIDF vectorizer (and COUNT vectorizer) to run as parallel jobs? Something similar to n_jobs=-1 parameter in other sklearn models.

Answer (score 15):

This is not directly possible because there is no way to parallelize/distribute access to the vocabulary that is needed for these vectorizers.

To perform parallel document vectorization, use the [`HashingVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) instead. The scikit docs provide [an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html) using this vectorizer to train (and evaluate) a classifier in batches. A similar workflow also works for parallelization because input terms are mapped to the same vector indices without any communication between the parallel workers.

Simply compute the partial term-doc matrices separately and concatenate them once all jobs are done. At this point you may also run [`TfidfTransformer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) on the concatenated matrix.

The most significant drawback of not storing the vocabulary of input terms, is that it is difficult to find out which terms are mapped to which column in the final matrix (i.e. inverse transform). The only efficient mapping is to use the hashing function on a term to see which column/index it is assigned to. For an inverse transform, you would need to do this for all unique terms (i.e. your vocabulary).

Comment: I like this answer, and I'm attempting to implement it, but how do I go about concatenating the results of the parallelized `HashingVectorizer`?

Comment: Nvm. I got it. I used `scipy.sparse.vstack`.

Comment: Can you explain more on getting back the corresponding vocabulary?

Comment: @Lei it is not a matter of "getting back" the corresponding vocabulary. The `HashingVectorizer` doesn't keep any tokens in memory. It relies on a hashing function to obtain an integer token ID every time a token is counted. If it is worth it, you could find the vocabulary by other means and use the hashing function to create a mapping from token IDs to token strings.

Answer (score 10):

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271381/7127519) is good however I would like to expand in an example with TfidfVectorizer.
I provide [here](https://github.com/rafaelvalero/ParallelTextProcessing/blob/master/parallelizing_text_processing.ipynb) and self-contained example, where you can see the elapsed time.
Basically after fitting the vectorizer (which is difficult to parallelise) you can transform (this bit is easier to parallelise).

You have something like this to fit the model:

```
print("Extracting tf-idf features")
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
t0 = time()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit(data_pd['text'])
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))
```

You have something like this to transform the data:

```
print("Transforming tf-idf features...")
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(data_pd['text'])
print("done in %0.3fs." % (time() - t0))
```

This is the bit that you can parallelise, I recommend something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import scipy.sparse as sp

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
num_partitions = num_cores-2 # I like to leave some cores for other
#processes
print(num_partitions)

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    a = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    del df
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    df = sp.vstack(pool.map(func, a), format='csr')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
 
def test_func(data):
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(data["text"])
    return tfidf_matrix
 

tfidf_parallel = parallelize_dataframe(data_pd, test_func)
```

The previous solution is an adaptation from [here](http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/).

I hope it helps. In my case it reduces the time a lot.

Comment: As of Apr 2020, I couldn't find any mention of `HashingVectorizer` becoming deprecated in sklearn docs or discussions. Please post a link if you see the contrary.