# Multiprocessing on SKLEARN instance methods

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am used to **map** and **starmap** pool methods to distribute a **FUNCTION** on any kind of *iterable object*. Here is how I typically  extract stem words from the *raw content* column of a pandas dataframe:

```
pool = mp.Pool(cpu_nb)
totalvocab_stemmed = pool.map(tokenize_and_stem, site_df["raw_content"])
pool.close()
```

[a good article on function parallelization in python](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/)

So far so good. But is there a nice and easy way to parallelize the execution of sklearn **METHODS**. Here is an example of what I would like to distribute

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.6, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words=stop_words,
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, ngram_range=(1,3))

tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(self.site_df["raw_content"])
```

**tfidf_matrix** is not an element by element list so splitting **site_df["raw_content"]** in as many elements as I have cores in my CPU to perform a GOF pool and stack everything back together later on is not an option. I saw **some interesting options**:

- the IPython.parallel Client [source](https://speakerdeck.com/valeriomaggio/parallel-and-large-scale-machine-learning-with-scikit-learn?slide=45)
- use the parallel_backend function of sklearn.externals.joblib as a context [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601026/easy-way-to-use-parallel-options-of-scikit-learn-functions-on-hpc)

I might be dumb but I wasn't very successful in both attempts. How would you do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396957/sklearn-tfidf-vectorizer-to-run-as-parallel-jobs You can just parallelize the transforming process afterwards, but the fitting process needs to be one process I think.