# Why scikit-learn switches to SequentialBackend?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, grid-search

I try to run the following code on a machine with 16 available CPUs:

```py
def tokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

param_grid = [{'vect__stop_words': [None, stop],
               'vect__binary': [True, False]}]

bow = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1), tokenizer=tokenizer)  
multinb_bow = Pipeline([('vect', bow), ('clf', MultinomialNB())])

gs_multinb_bow = GridSearchCV(multinb_bow, param_grid, scoring='f1_macro', 
                              cv=3, verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)

gs_multinb_bow.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I set `n_jobs` to `-1`, but `scikit-learn` switches to `SequentialBackend`, even if I add a context manager `with parallel_backend('loky'):` and the script still runs using only 1 concurrent worker.

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 12 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
```

Same result persists if I specify a different value for `n_jobs`.

Why is this happening? I recently ran what seems to be an identical code on a similar task, and grid search worked in parallel on multiple CPUs, as specified by `n_jobs` using `LokyBackend`.

Comment: Hi, any chance you found a solution for this issue of ```Sklearn``` switching to ```sequential backend```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396957/sklearn-tfidf-vectorizer-to-run-as-parallel-jobs