# faster sklearn tf-idf vectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, spacy

I was trying to use sklearn's TfidfVectorizer for a project, but Tfidf Vectorizer seems to take up a lot of time...

```
import spacy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def tokenize_spacy(sentence):
    nlp = spacy.load('ja_core_news_lg')
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    return [w.text for w in doc]

def read_corpus(filename):
    corpus = []
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            corpus.append(line)
    return corpus

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize_spacy, ngram_range=(1, 4), stop_words=stop_words)
corpus = read_corpus(args.corpus)
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

The model `'ja_core_news_lg'` is from [here](https://spacy.io/models/ja), and the size of the corpus file is 2.7 GB, `stop_words` is an array whose length is less than 100. The vectorizer has been running for more than 48 hours so I was wondering whether there's a way to more efficiently fit the vectorizer or whether there's a faster substitution.

I have 56 CPUs but this program seems only to run on one of them. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396957/sklearn-tfidf-vectorizer-to-run-as-parallel-jobs/36271381#36271381) answer but since I need to do `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`afterward so using  `HashingVectorizer` doesn't seem to be a good fit for me.

Any help will be appreciated and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Vectorizer is not the problem, it is the tokenizer which slows you down.

For each document, the tokenize-function reloads the spacy model, which obviously takes a lot of time. Instead, try to load the spacy model just once:

```
nlp = spacy.load('ja_core_news_lg')

def tokenize_spacy(sentence):
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    return [w.text for w in doc]

def read_corpus(filename):
    corpus = []
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            corpus.append(line)
    return corpus

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize_spacy, ngram_range=(1, 4), stop_words=stop_words)
corpus = read_corpus(args.corpus)
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

Does it make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this before, I've tried this approach but it doesn't work :( it is running for more than 45 hrs, too.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested both ways with 500 dummy sentences: Mine took 2.8 seconds, yours at least 10 minutes (and still running )

Comment: Yes :( I am pretty sure about that! Your way has run on my machine for over 70 hrs considering the fact that my data is 60 million lines...