# how can i refactor my python code to decrease the time complexity

Tags: python, refactoring

this code takes 9 sec which is very long time, i guess the problem in 2 loop in my code

```
for symptom in symptoms:
  # check if the symptom is mentioned in the user text
  norm_symptom = symptom.replace("_"," ")
  for combin in list_of_combinations:
    print(getSimilarity([combin, norm_symptom]))
    if getSimilarity([combin,norm_symptom])>0.25:
       if symptom not in extracted_symptoms:
        extracted_symptoms.append(symptom)
```

i tried  to use zip like this:

```
for symptom, combin in zip(symptoms,list_of_combinations):
  norm_symptom = symptom.replace("_"," ")
  if (getSimilarity([combin, norm_symptom]) > 0.25 and symptom not in extracted_symptoms):
    extracted_symptoms.append(symptom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict to store the results of getSimilarity for each combination and symptom. This way, you can avoid calling getSimilarity multiple times for the same combination and symptom. This way it will be more efficient, thus faster.

```
import collections

similarity_results = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for symptom in symptoms:
   norm_symptom = symptom.replace("_"," ")
   for combin in list_of_combinations:
       # Check if the similarity has already been computed
       if combin in similarity_results[symptom]:
          similarity = similarity_results[symptom][combin]
       else:
          similarity = getSimilarity([combin, norm_symptom])
          similarity_results[symptom][combin] = similarity
   if similarity > 0.25:
       if symptom not in extracted_symptoms:
           extracted_symptoms.append(symptom)
```

Update:

Alternatively You could use an algorithm based on the Levenshtein distance, which is a measure of the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions, or substitutions) required to transform one string into another. Python-Levenshtein library does that.

```
import Levenshtein

def getSimilarity(s1, s2):
    distance = Levenshtein.distance(s1, s2)
    return 1.0 - (distance / max(len(s1), len(s2)))

extracted_symptoms = []
for symptom, combin in zip(symptoms, list_of_combinations):
    norm_symptom = symptom.replace("_", " ")
    if (getSimilarity(combin, norm_symptom) > 0.25) and (symptom not in extracted_symptoms):
        extracted_symptoms.append(symptom)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still takes the same time

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're algorithm is slow because of the 2 nested loops.

It performs with big O N*M (see more here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/big-o-notation-why-it-matters-and-why-it-doesnt-1674cfa8a23c/)

N being the lenght of symptoms
and M being the list_of_combinations

What can takes time also is the computation `getSimilarity`, what is this operation ?

Comment: getSimilarity get the similarity rate between symptom and user text 

list_of_combinations and symptoms are big arrays thats why it takes a long time

def getSimilarity(extracted_list):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(extracted_list)
    return cosine_similarity(vectors[0], vectors[1])

Comment: What is the length of `symptoms` and `list_of_combinations` ?
With every algorithm, you will have to computer `similarities` for every couple of them, so the double loop is unavoidable.

What's the usage of this code ? 9s can be acceptable dependeing of your need, maybe you can explain more deeply this part.

You can also try to optimize your computation with another Vectorizer that can work in parallele (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271381/18364469 for more)